# How to pass data from $state.go() to the data parameter in stateprovider in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having trouble passing some data to the stateprovider using $state.go(). Here is the sample code that we have been using.

```
$stateProvider.state('socialform', {
        url: "/socialform?webcontent",
        templateUrl: "base_template/_Sends.html?",
        data: { pageTitle: 'Social & Website Publishing' },
        resolve: {
            callPreRenderServices: callPreRenderServices
        }
    });


$scope.isWebContent = function(status) {
    if(status) {
        $state.go('socialform', {webcontent:true});
    }
    else {
        $state.go('socialform');
    }        
};
```

Basically, what we need to be doing is to pass a title variable to $state.go() so that it will replace the pageTitle to whatever is the value of the passed variable.

From the code above to this:

```
$stateProvider.state('socialform', {
        url: "/socialform?webcontent",
        templateUrl: "base_template/_Sends.html?",
        data: { pageTitle: title },
        resolve: {
            callPreRenderServices: callPreRenderServices
        }
    });


$scope.isWebContent = function(status) {
    if(status) {
        $state.go('socialform', {webcontent:true, title:"some title"});
    }
    else {
        $state.go('socialform', {title:"another title"});
    }        
};
```

Comment: Why don't you use a variable in a service that you setup in your isWebContent function, and resolve in your route ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service :

```
module.service('titleService', function() {
    this.title = null;
});

// ... inject titleService in the calling controller ...
$scope.isWebContent = function(status) {
    if(status) {
        titleService.title = 'Some Title'
        $state.go('socialform');
    }
    else {
        titleService.title = 'Another Title'
        $state.go('socialform');
    }        
};
```

Then, you can either inject it in via custom data or, via the resolve function :

```
// ... inject before route definition, via dependency injection
data = { title: titleService.title };
$stateProvider.state('socialform', {
    url: "/socialform?webcontent",
    templateUrl: "base_template/_Sends.html?",

    // like this
    data: data,

    resolve: {
        callPreRenderServices: callPreRenderServices
        // Or you can resolve your title from your service
        // and use pageTitle in your controller
        pageTitle: ['titleService', function(titleService) { 
            return titleService.title; 
        }]
    }
});
```

You could also pass it as a $state parameter :

```
$stateProvider.state('socialform', {
    url: "/socialform/:webcontent/:title",
    // ...
});

// ...

$state.go('socialform', {webcontent: 'something', title: 'some other thing'});
```